# Is it possible to bind filename with javascript on apex repeat?

Tags: apex, javascript, repeat, apexinputfile, bind-variable

I have a simple apex repeat with add filename tag. When I add the following line "inputfile" the previous line shows no file chosen. Is it possible to bind the filename with the inputfile button with javascript?

Apex

```
<apex:repeat value="{!newAttachments}" var="newAtt">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Upload photo"/>                         
                <apex:inputFile id="inputfile" value="{!newAtt.body}" filename="{!newAtt.name}"/><br/>
            </apex:repeat><br/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Add More" action="{!addMore}"  onclick="checkFileSize(event);"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is a security feature of the browser. The user must select/input the file name, and it is read-only from JavaScript's perspective.

Comment: So its not possible on the client side to show the previous selected files?

Comment: @Thomas Correct. Sorry to disappoint, that's just how it is.

Comment: @sfdcfoc That is a bummer. But I solved it by adding 5 upload options from the start so the files stay filled. Thanks for clarifying